# Error when load the database into MySQL server

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am trying to load [the database](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/employee/en/) into MySQL server using "File" -> "Run SQL Script..." and open "employees.sql". In the pop-up window, I don't make any changes and then press "Run", everything is like in [this video](https://youtu.be/qHjvGAMPzEw). But I get the following error:[image]

and each time a new `.cnf` file is generated in the "Temp" folder.

Couldn't find a solution on the internet. Please help me understand why this is happening and how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

something is using the file which you are trying to open/work on.

you can use `handle.exe` from sysinternals to be able to find which process is holding the file. then kill the process.

```
handle.exe tmp8cbfil.cnf
handle.exe employees.sql
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice, but nothing was found this way...